# Is there a simple formula to calculate these codes?

Tags: algorithm, encoding

```
Switch 1 can be set to F or S.
Switch 2 can be set to M or A or C or N.
Switch 3 can be set to U or B.
Switch 4 can be set to Z or Y.
```

The following 3-digit numbers (believed to be decimal)
represent the combination of switch settings shown.
No other combinations matter or will be encountered.

```
036 == F, M, U, Z
037 == S, M, U, Z
040 == F, M, B, Y
041 == F, M, U, Y
042 == S, M, B, Y
043 == S, M, U, Y
080 == F, A, B, Z
081 == F, A, U, Z
082 == F, C, B, Z
083 == F, C, U, Z
090 == S, A, B, Z
091 == S, A, U, Z
092 == S, C, B, Z
093 == S, C, U, Z
140 == F, A, B, Y
141 == F, A, U, Y
142 == S, A, B, Y
143 == S, A, U, Y
240 == F, C, B, Y
241 == F, C, U, Y
242 == S, C, B, Y
243 == S, C, U, Y
260 == F, N, U, Z
261 == S, N, U, Z
270 == F, N, U, Y
271 == S, N, U, Y
300 == F, N, B, Z
301 == S, N, B, Z
310 == F, N, B, Y
311 == S, N, B, Y
700 == F, M, B, Z
702 == S, M, B, Z
```

Is there a simple formula (not a lookup table or tree)
for calculating the 3-digit number from the switch settings?
It's OK if the formula includes combinations not listed
above, since those will never be input.

Comment: Really?, you don't define any modus ponens rules and you expect us to do your work for you?

Comment: This isn't really a programming question, but it _is_ interesting.  Just curious: what's the source?  Homework? Game? Treasure map?

Comment: Convert the left side to binary. Convert the right side to 0/1(/2/3) per letter. Try to find a pattern or add to the description.

Comment: It looks like a lookup table is in your future :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've got is [a subset of USPS service codes](https://ribbs.usps.gov/intelligentmail_mailpieces/documents/tech_guides/stid.pdf).  F is First Class, S is Standard, M is manual, A is ASR, C is CSR, N is none, B is basic, U is full, Z is no confirm, Y is confirm.  The full set of codes makes it even less likely there's an easy formula, but you could try contacting the USPS designers.

Comment: thank-you so much!  this has been bugging me since it was posted.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like something you could solve with [karnaugh maps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map) or one of its equivalents (for example [Quine-McCluskey algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine%E2%80%93McCluskey_algorithm))

This way, the binary representation of your 3 digit numbers are your outputs, and you have 5 inputs, 1 bit each for switches 1, 3 and 4 and two bits for switch 2.

If your input is fixed (so you don't need to write a program to give you the expression), you might benefit more from mixing the karnaugh method with additional operations that you know. Karnaugh maps give you and-or expressions, but in your application you may also have addition, and other operations available which you can use.

Comment: That would be three really ugly Karnaugh maps!

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, those are the most common ways to get an expression for an output based on some input in hardware design. If it gets ugly, well tough luck.

Comment: Well, I've done my share of Karnaugh maps back in my embedded days, so the area is familiar to me. Solving a 5-variable KM is no fun, not to mention the non-readable code that you'll get as your output. IMO, a small 32-entry lookup table will work better.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, in fact, it's a 10-variable KM, 5 of them (because there are 5 outputs), so yeah it's worse than you thought! :D However, I believe quine-mcclusky should be pretty doable. The key point here is that most of this guy's data is "don't care". Also, the quine mcclusky algorithm is most definitely already written and the OP can use it. As a side note, I would have also used a lookup table, but hey, the OP explicitly asked for a way that doesn't involve lookup tables.!